# PHP file upload failed to move file

Tags: php, file-upload

I created this script by myself, security will be looked into once I get it to actually upload a file, but at the moment I am getting the following errors:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(public_html/uploads/rikkles/1/apt&c-application-
>       form-2005.pdf) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or 
>       directory in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage22/sf/pa/ys/sfpayslips.info/public_html/login
>       /upload.php on line 16

error:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 
>        '/tmp/phpz4zlrR' to 'public_html/uploads/rikkles/1/apt&c-application-form-2005.pdf' in 
>        /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage22/sf/pa/ys/sfpayslips.info/public_html/login/upload.php 
>        on line 16

Here is the code:

```
if($_POST["upload"]){

$target_path = 'public_html/uploads/' . strtolower(str_replace(' ','',$_POST["username"])) . '/' . $_POST["month"] . '/' . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

$filename = basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

$ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);

if (($ext == "pdf") && ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "application/pdf") && ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["size"] < 550000)) {
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)){
        echo "<div class='success'>The file " . "<span class='filename'>" . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) . "</span>" . " has been uploaded</div>";
    } else {
        echo "<div class='error'>There was an error uploading the file, please try again!</div>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<div class='error'>You can only upload PDF file types</div>";
}
print $target_path;
}
```

Comment: You are likely missing a leading slash in `public_html`. Or something else is wrong with the target path

Comment: Use absolute path for `$target_path`

Comment: Have You tried to upload a file without an ampersand?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, it was a path issue, for security reasons the files are uploaded outside of the application folder so I used $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] to get the ABSPATH.